# The expectation value of momentum in an infinite well stationary state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

For a particle in an infinite well potential given by:

[image]

I am able to successful derive the normalized wavefunction as:

$$u_n(x) =\sqrt{2/a}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})$$

where this normalization has the appropriate dimensionality for a one-dimensional wavefunction, but that the sign (or more generally the phase) of the normalization constant is purely conventional, and $-\sqrt{2/a}$ or $\exp⁡(iθ) \sqrt{2/a}$ would serve just as well.

The most general solutions will be linear combination of these energy eigenstates with their associated time-dependence:

[image]

The expectation value of momentum in an infinite well stationary state is given by:

[image]

•Since the eigenfunctions vanish at the boundaries.

•Thus, the average value of the momentum vanishes in each eigenstate

In the book i am reading for it says this:

> The energy eigenstates in this (or any) bound state system can be
> chosen to be purely real functions (or real with multiplicative
> complex phases that are independent of position).  As the calculation
> in above illustrates, this implies that the expectation value $⟨p ̂
> > ⟩$, which we know must be real, can be written as a purely real
> integral time i.

I don't understand this

> 'can be written as a purely real integral time i.'

---

The extract from the textbook:

[image]

Equation

[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335212/

Comment: Surely the last words  "time i" are just a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362305/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233266/2451 and links therein.